# Why does the potential in simple harmonic motion contain only even powers?

Tags: potential-energy, harmonic-oscillator, approximations

The lecturer was showing that any system (almost) will behave as SHM if we move it by a small $\alpha$ from its equilibrium point. For doing so, he wrote the potential of the motion as $$U=U_0+\frac{dU}{d\alpha}\Big|_{\alpha=0}\alpha+\frac12\frac{d^2U}{d\alpha}\Big|_{\alpha=0}\alpha^2+...=U_0+\frac12\frac{d^2U}{d\alpha}\Big|_{\alpha=0}\alpha^2+...$$
Where did the odd powers go?

Comment: I think that in general the bottom of a potential well will have odd powers. It was probably being assumed that the potential was symmetric about alpha=0, in which case only the even power coefficients are non-zero.

Comment: Of course, the coefficient for the very first odd power of alpha has to be zero because it is assumed that alpha=0 corresponds to the minimum of the potential well. However, in general the coefficients of all the other odd powers of alpha after that (i.e., 3, 5, 7, ..) can be non-zero.

Answer (score 3):

It is a Taylor expansion and it is described [here](http://www.people.fas.harvard.edu/~djmorin/waves/oscillations.pdf) .

Your $\alpha$ is  really $(x  - x_0)$ where $x_0$ is the equilibrium position and the second term is zero due to the fact that we are looking at a minimum of the potential, so the slope (the derivative of $U$) should be zero at the minimum.

Higher order terms are ignored because of their small values with respect to second order.

The approximation is valid for small displacements around a minimum. For completely symmetric potentials there could not be odd terms.

Answer (score 0):

if we not consider the taylor expansion in a mathematical view， think naively if a particle stay at the equilibrium point of a potential well, it would not want to go any side with an infinitesimal distance deviation. This actually means the $U^\prime=0$  and other odd terms like this vanish because odd mean asymmetric of the two sides. Harmonic motion is symmetric.